# Phantomjs crash on multiple calls from nodejs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am developing a project in which I need to spawn/exec multiple processes from nodejs to call phantomjs about 50-100 which should easily handled.
These are the steps which I follow:

1.nodejs (infinite loop) which always run to check for a condition, and if   condition met then,

2. nodejs spawn or exec a new process to call phantomjs.

although I exit (phantom.exit()) after completing phantom task, still If I exec too many processes let say 100  from nodejs, in most of the phantomjs processes output I get phantomjs crashed.

Is it because of the too many processes?but I think 50-100 are not too many, such a widely used framework (phantomjs) must be able to handle min 500 requests I think.

Please help if I am going wrong somewhere and If I am missing something.

I am currently using exec tp calll phantom

```
child = execFile(binPath, args, function (error, stdout, stderr) { ---my code here---- });
```

and phantomjs files are too long , I think this will be enough that I am exiting them:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        phantom.exit();
    }, 0);
```

Thank in advance :)

Comment: what do you mean under crash? do you have any crash log or some messages about crash?

Comment: `localStorage` is shared across multiple PhantomJS processes, because it's always written to the disk. Maybe there is a lock limit for the `localStorage` database, which crashes PhantomJS.

Comment: Hi @alexey it sometimes says phantomjs crash and gives the log file path, which I can't read , and sometimes process just stops in between with fail.

Comment: Hi @ArtjomB. I am quite new to it and don't know much about it, I'll search for it, but I'll be thankful if you could tell me how could I change it if it is set to limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I did to resolve it,
I executed only 30 requests at a time and kept rest of them in a queue , I increemented the counter from 0 to 30 for first 30 requests and then when a request finishes decremented it by 1 for each.
I kept a requestQueue where I keep putting every request something like this:

```
var requestQueue = {}
var counter = 0;
requestQueue.push(--anyreq--);

    setInterval(function() { // check frequently if there is a space to send more request to phantom

    if(counter < 30 && requestQueue.length > 0 ){
            counter++;   //increement the counter while sending spawning req for phantom

            var reqforPhantom = requestQueue.shift(); 

    //spawn or exec a req for phantomjs sending 'reqforPhantom' (this is something you want to send to phantom script, if you don't want to send anything you could remove request queue from this code) variable
    //decrement the counter on response
              counter--;
    }
    },100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory consumed is a function of amount of processes and the memory used per process. I would think memory leaks would have a larger impact the more child processes you are running.

Phantomjs has a known memory leak. This could be your issue.

Exec your PhantomJS child process again after around 50 page loads or so.

You could pass in the information needed to pick up again where you left off by passing in a command line argument.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11390

Comment: Hi @therewillbecode ,
I am already doing exec one after the other, 2nd page load after 1st is a new exec and therefore a new process, did you mean that I should wait for first 50 to complete?

btw, provided link says at the end that using phantom2.0 would resolve it, and I am already using phantom2.0. though I din't tried with "--load-images=true", I don't know what diff will it make, but I'll try it for sure
Thanks a lot for your quick reply

Comment: What I mean is not to leave a single process running for too long. So if a single task is longer than say 50 paginations break it up into multiple exec processes. Let me know if this is clear or not.

Comment: Hi Thanks, but it is not clear to me. How to break phantomjs process, ex- If I need to post status on fb I need to login and then post status , and this can be done in a single process, if I login in 1 process and try to post status in 2nd then Its not possible, coz we cannot post without getting logged in
I am opening different domains in different processes, for ex- I exec a process open gmail and complete task of gmail in this 1 process only, simultaneously I open fb, yahoo etc and complete their tasks in their resp. process.

I exec them all differently so they are all different processes.

Comment: Thanks @therewillbecode I resolved it , not exactly this but yea something related to it.